# Need CallBack whenever Thread created by DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch mehod reloads the log4j.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j

**Java Code :** 
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfigFile.getAbsolutePath(),100000L);

I need to add some appenders programmaticaly whenever Thread created by configureAndWatch method reloads the log4j.xml.

Actually i am setting some appenders programmatically but its get reset when Thread reloads the log4j.xml so i need to again add the appenders programmatically.For this i need a callback when ever Thread reloads the log4j.xml

Any Idea ?? How do i do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Log4j does not provide a way to register a callback on configuration load. It just creates a "watchdog" thread to monitor the file and reload configuration on file changes.

The only way I see it done is by spawning your own thread that reloads configuration and also adds the extra appenders.

Instead of :

```
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfigFile.getAbsolutePath(), 100000L);
```

you do this:

```
String configFilename = log4jConfigFile.getAbsolutePath();
DOMConfigurator.configure(configFilename);

// set your appenders programmatically here
// ...

MyXMLWatchdog watchDogThread = new MyXMLWatchdog(configFilename);
watchDogThread.setDelay(100000L);
watchDogThread.start();
```

You configured Log4j, added the appenders and started the monitoring thread. In the thread you reload configuration on file change:

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class MyXMLWatchdog extends FileWatchdog {
    public MyXMLWatchdog(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    public void doOnChange() {
        new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure(this.filename, LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
        // set your appenders programmatically here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Have a look at the source code of these classes for further details: [DOMConfigurator](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.java.html) (scroll to the bottom) and [FileWatchdog](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.java.html).

My suggestion though will be to just have everything configured in the `log4j.xml` file and not resort to workarounds.

P.S. You don't mention what type of Java application you have, but be aware that [`configureAndWatch` comes with a warning in Java EE applications](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6) as the thread does not stop on application shutdowns; it stops only on JVM shutdown.